# How to create view file to show details and retrieve form output?

Tags: php, yii

I am creating a *Question and Answers* view to show some *Question* to the user and retrieve answers to those questions from users.

i tried using `CListView`, but it can only be used to show the question only, it can not be used to retrieve answers back.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,  'model'=>$model,
    'itemView'=>'_view', )); ?>
```

Could anybody having experience on creating view file to show details and retrieve form output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I don;t think there is any such view helper..But I've implemented such functionality using Listview..

Include this in your question index file which is calling the listview(The code you've written)

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->createUrl("question/answer");?>">
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'_view',
        'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
    )); ?>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Include These Lines in your _view file called from listview..I presume id is the question_id..

```
    <input type="text" name="Question[<?php echo $data->id; ?>]" />
```

Now For Each question there will be a textbox with name Question[question_id] and one submit button that will have action to question controller's function answer in which you can insert the answers into database or can do anything with the answers..

```
public function actionAnswer()
{
    foreach ($_GET['post'] as $key=>$ans)
    {
        echo $key; //Question Id
        echo $ans;//Answer sent by the user
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rajat for your answer, Also i would like to ask you that is there a way we can create our own wigets or are there wigets extensions. primarily my question where can i get information about yii user interface programming to cater more advance user interface requiremets